# Repeat sequence multiple times (seq and rep functions)

Tags: r

I have the code below;

```
seq(rep(1, 7, by = 2), times = 7)
```

which gives an error shown below;

> Warning message: In seq.default(rep(1, 7, by = 2), times = 3) :
>    extra argument 'times' will be disregarded
>   Error: 'from' must be of length 1

How do I rectify the error?

Answer (score 2):

You have the functions the wrong way around.

`rep(seq(1, 7, by = 2), times = 7)`

Comment: don't think answering typo questions will be any use for anyone except the OP